# How to make dots in gganimate appear and not transition

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gganimate

I am using gganimate. Say I have this MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) +
    geom_point(color = 'red', size = 1) +
    transition_time(Month) +
    shadow_mark(colour = 'black', size = 0.75)
```

I have one question: how can I make the new points just appear as opposed to transitioning from the old ones? Put another way, I just want the new dots to appear at their final location and not have a transition. How should I modify the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transitions are ultimately tied to each data point's `group`. In your code, all the Day 1 data points are sharing a group, and so they appear from the old ones.

Give the points their own group (e.g. by using `group = interaction(Month, Day)`) and it should work.

```
a <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp, 
                            group = interaction(Month, Day))) +
  geom_point(color = 'red', size = 1) +
  transition_time(Month) +
  shadow_mark(colour = 'black', size = 0.75) +
  enter_fade()  # I liked the look of this, but fine to leave out
animate(a, nframes = 100)
```

[image]