# How to control appearance of flashing dots in gganimate

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, plot, gganimate

Say that I have these data that I want to animate with `ggplot2`+`gganimate`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

data <- data.frame(day = c(1:5, 1:5), 
    x = c(rep(2,5), rep(4, 5)), 
    y=c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)))

data <- data[c(1:2, 4:10),]
```

The goals of the animation/question are to

No. 1. have flashing red dots for each day+x+y dot that is in the dataset (meaning there is an observation for that day+x+y). The flash should be very brief. After it flashes, it should go to the background color (controlled by shadow_mark) of black. Note that I do not want dots to float around, only stay where they are (see solution to this question: [How to make dots in gganimate appear and not transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411604/how-to-make-dots-in-gganimate-appear-and-not-transition)).

No. 2. I also want the dots to flash beginning exactly when their day begins. Here is code that does only part of what I want, but fails to (fully) address numbers 1 and 2:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x,y, group=interaction(x,y))) +
    geom_point(color="red", size=3) +
    transition_time(day) +
    shadow_mark(color="black", size=3) +
    theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.7)) +      
    labs(subtitle = paste('day: {frame_time}'))  -> a

anim_save("test.gif", a, end_pause=6, width = 400, height = 450, duration=15)
```

Here is the resulting animation:

[image]

This has two problems that I hope to get resolved:

1. The dots do not only flash momentarily, but flash much too long. In other words, I would like to see a red dot briefly, then black dot, then red dot, etc.
2. There is also a problem with when the flash begins. This is illustrated when the dot turns to black (because `data` is missing day 3 for the (x=2,y=1) dot) as expected. However it turns to black partway through day 3 and turns back to red partway through day 4, but I would like it to turn to black exactly at when day 3 begins and flash red exactly when day 4 begins. Note that I am not sure if this time misalignment is caused by `transition_time` behavior or the subtitle `frame_time` behavior or something else.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the dots to persist for more than the day they start in?

Comment: Yes. In my actual application, I want the dots to flash on the day they appear (similar to flashing red in your answer), and then persist (equivalent to the black), but actually use an alpha of, say, 0.1. So that the first time the day appears, the black dot will be a light gray, the second time, it will get a little darker, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach where the data is prepped to give 25 frames to each day, where the color is made to flash for just the first of those:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
f_per_day <- 25
animate(
  data %>%
    uncount(f_per_day, .id = "frame") %>%
    mutate(time = day + (frame-1)/f_per_day) %>%

    ggplot(aes(x, y, color = frame == 1)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"), guide = F) +
    theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.7)) +      
    labs(subtitle = paste('day: {floor(frame_time*10)/10}')) +
    transition_time(time),

  width = 400, 
  height = 450, 
  fps = 25, 
  type = "cairo")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind a quick follow-up question, which aspect of you code fixed problem 2? Also, I plan to award you the bounty later when I can; I have to wait a while for some reason.

Comment: I think the transitions were happening prematurely in the old data because gganimate was pulling in the closest color value for the time, and your original data was granular to the day. So at a point in time of day "3.5" it would go to the 4 value. By feeding it more frames, that problem is reduced, or entirely eliminated if the data has the same granularity as the frame rate.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks!